# The use of the verb "do" in context

Tags: word-choice

Tell me please If I used the right word in the following sentence

> I have been **doing** powerlifting for 3 years.

Does the sentence sound natural? if it dosn't, would it be better If use the word *practise* instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds natural enough but **doing** is [unnecessary](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27ve%20been%20powerlifting%22&oq=%22I%27ve%20been%20powerlifting%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.6561j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).